Proving that every first order differential equation with a general solution has an integrating factor
My textbook claims that every first order differential equation of the form $$P(x,y)+Q(x,y)\cdot y'=0$$ has an integrating factor such that $$IP+IQ\cdot y'=0$$ is an exact differential equation. The proof (which is adapted from the same textbook) is given here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_Integrating_Factor#:~:text=Then%20it%20is%20always%20possible,Solution%20to%20Exact%20Differential%20Equation.
However, I am unable to follow several steps in the proof (division of the DE by various functions which are assumed to be non-zero everywhere without explanation, to name one), and thus request a rigorous proof of the statement along with the conditions/assumptions under which it is true. Moreovoer, I also request a precise defintion of the type of integration factor whose existence is being gauranteed here, since multilpying out by $I=0$ clearly makes every differential equation exact but is not considered an integration factor.
